# I cannot convert a Blob file to base64 and save it in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have the following method in my Vue component:

```js
  methods: {
    async saveFile() {
      const { valid } = await this.$refs.file.validate();
      if (valid) {
        this.$emit("uploadFile", this.file);
      }
    },
  },
```

I am trying to test this method by trying to convert a blob to base64. But the problem is that `wrapper.vm.file` gives a `null` instead of the base64 file. And if the file isn't validated in the method `saveFile()` then, the `$emit` event won't happen.

I am not experienced with JavaScript, so other suggestions for the test would be great too!

```js
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        
reader.onloadend = async function () {
    var base64data = reader.result;
    wrapper.vm.file = base64data
}
reader.onloadend()
await wrapper.vm.saveFile()
await Vue.nextTick()
expect(wrapper.emitted()).toHaveProperty('uploadFile')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found npm package that solves your problem. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-to-base64)

If you dont want to install the package then you can just copy the code from the repo as it is simple (https://github.com/tiaanduplessis/blob-to-base64/blob/master/src/index.js)

You use the package like so https://github.com/tiaanduplessis/blob-to-base64#readme